# I need a way get rid of using && operator so much

Tags: c#

I need to compare two objects of the same type but with a lot of prop

```
return string.Equals(x.Name, y.Name) && 
x.Price == y.Price && 
string.Equals(x.Species, y.Species) && 
x.AgeEnforced == y.AgeEnforced &&
x.MinimumAge == y.MinimumAge && 
string.Equals(x.WeightRange, y.WeightRange) && 
x.MinimumWeight == y.MinimumWeight
```

The list goes on up to 14 props

A hint on how can I lose `&&` operator?

Comment: If you are willing to use a library, you could use [`DeepEqual`](https://github.com/jamesfoster/DeepEqual)

Comment: Look at [IEquatable<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) interface

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? It's perfectly readable, though the formatting could be improved :)

Comment: You could overload the `Equals` (and `GetHashCode`) method of whatever `x` and `y` are and put this code there.

Comment: Put a `#region`/`#endregion` around it so you don't have to look at it.

Comment: @Chump Because memory management is a known problem that I don't want to solve over and over again.

Comment: @Chump Because they don't want to waste many hours writing tedious memory management code and chasing wild pointer write bugs?

Comment: @Chump Because when we switched to C#, we found we were getting actual releasable features out the door in half the time. And I've wasted enough of my life tracking down other people's memory leaks, thanks.

Comment: We have std::unique_ptr now. What memory leaks? ;-)

Comment: You're going to be pretty hard pressed to replace a two character operator with anything sorter than that.  Even if you found a one character operator that did the same thing, you're saving all of one character, not exactly a significant improvement.

Comment: @Chump You sound like one of those emacs guys who think Picard could beat up Kirk.

Comment: Sometimes there is no better way to write your code. If the business logic demands that these checks be made, then that is what you have to do.

Comment: DeepEqual is the perfect solution for me :)
Thanks BWA!

Comment: && is no better or worse than || or + or - or * - they all have their purpose. It's not like && is time consuming or anything.

Answer (score 5):

If your class has 14 properties and all of them have to be compared to ensure equality, all of these checks have to be made somewhere. No matter if you put them into a (maybe static) helper method, the Equals-method, a class that implements IEqualityComparer (IMHO the best choice), an extension method or whatever else comes to your mind, you have to write down all of these checks once.

Instead of writing these checks on yourself you can use some reflection stuff (or a library that makes use of it) by iterating over all properties, but that's normally not the best choice, cause it is slower and equality checks are tend to be called very often (sort, hashset, etc.). So take the pain and write the checks down.

If you think these are too many checks, then maybe your object is to fat and has to much properties. Maybe it needs a deeper hierarchy by using classes which are representing a part of the whole thing and you have a top class that has as property a child class and then you write the compare method for each child class individually and the top class just calls these comparers for its child classes.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to *A hint on how can i lose && operator?*

```
if (string.Equals(x.Name, y.Name) == false) return false;
if (x.Price != y.Price) return false

// ... others

return true;
```

Comment: I think the idea was less about removing the operator from the code and more about not having to methodically do each check, but this does answer the question as stated.

Comment: you've replace two characters of code with 17 characters of code.  You've made the code 8x *more verbose* than the OP's code, with no improvement to the semantics.

Comment: @Servy, I am from `vb.net` background - I "like" verbose code :)

Comment: Also it's more instructions to do, so that answer not really convinces me.

Comment: Write `if (!string.Equals(x.Name, y.Name)) return false` !

Comment: @Fabio I have a feeling your answer is sarcastic (by _litrally_ replaceing the `&&` operator with something _worse_), but the `&&` effectively does exactly what you are doing since it short-circuits and will return `false` the first time it finds a `false` operand

Comment: This has the nice property of being easier to debug! When single-steeping though a misbehaving return value, this lets us known which comparison broken the chain quite easily. Good luck with that with the &&. Other than that, I don't find any differences really.

Comment: @Alejandro You can accomplish the same thing, if you truly find it necessary, just using `&&` and a boolean variable that you update as you go, while still avoiding the massive increase in boilerplate.

Comment: as Alejandro said, the debugging convenience is actually very high. Diagnosing why a multiple chained && returned 'false' is a real pain if there are more than 3-4 terms in the chain. Moreover, you cannot place a breakpoint in a middle of the expression to quickly catch a specific case. Sure, you can place a conditional breakpoint, but then, with long expression, it's really irritating in the long run. **ANY** way of writing the multiple-chained-&& is a plus, be it if() or &&= or whatever.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Well if you have something like `if (a && b && c && d)` and you stop on that in the debugger, if you hover over the first  `&&` a tooltip will tell you if `a && b` is true or false. If you hover over the second `&&`, a tooltip tells you if `a && b && c` is true or false. If you hover over the third `&&` a tooltip tells you if `a && b && c && d` is true or false. This tells you all you need to know without all that tedious and uneccessary splitting up of the expression... (Also you can hover over `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` to see their individual values.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson: have you tried doing a hover 30 times in a row? Several times because you were in a loop and didn't know which element false'd on which term? I did. Some legacy code had such expression chains. Sure, you can try bisecting. But even so, doing that for N elements because you're in a loop is not what I would want to do every day. Why not just place a breakpoint and go? I mean, 3, 4, okay,  maybe even 6 chained &&/|| are fine. But 14? 30? no, not for me. By the way, it's also a problem for diff/merge utils, because often &&/|| chains are "compacted" for "brevity" into fewer lines.

Comment: anyways, that's about cosmetics and comfort. functionality is the same, so there's not much to argue further about. Just use what you like :)

Comment: this answer 
1. is just longer
2. does not answers the question

Comment: @Dexion. it is perfectly answer a question  _how can i lose && operator?_ - question was even added to the answer.  :) but I understand the reason of your comment ...

Comment: Question was how to avoid 14 manual if or &&, etc, not how to rewrite the syntax, especially not to a longer form. This is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

This code must be somewhere. If this is only place where this code exist this is ok in my opinion. Bu if it exists in many places then you can move it to some helper fuction or override `Equals()` method in your object. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) info.

Example how to oveeride and use `Equals()`:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
   
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        MyObject o = obj as MyObject;

        if (o == null)
            return false;

        if (this.Name != o.Name)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serves as the default hash function. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A hash code for the current object.
    /// </returns>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        MyObject o1 = new MyObject()
        {
            Name = "a",
            Price = 1
        };

        MyObject o2 = new MyObject()
        {
            Name = "b",
            Price = 1
        };

        MyObject o3 = new MyObject()
        {
            Name = "a",
            Price = 1
        };

        Console.WriteLine("o1 == o2: {0}", o1.Equals(o2));
        Console.WriteLine("o1 == o3: {0}", o1.Equals(o3));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Result is:

> o1 == o2: False
>
> o1 == o3: True

Answer (score 0):

For me, `&&` or `||` are pretty short already. Your problem lies not in the operator itself, but in the way you are doing the comparison of 14+ properties.

Instead of writing all the property-comparisons by hand, you can try automating it.

```
var props_string = new List<Func<MyObject, string>>();
props_string.Add(foo => foo.Name);
props_string.Add(foo => foo.Species);
//..

var props_double = new List<Func<MyObject, double>>();
props_double.Add(foo => foo.Price);
//..
```

Now, having them listed, you can ran a loop over it

```
MyObject first = ...;
MyObject second = ...;

bool areEqual = true;

foreach(var prop in props_string)
    if(!string.Equals(prop(first), prop(second)))
        areEqual = false;

foreach(var prop in props_double)
    if(prop(first) != prop(second))
        areEqual = false;

return areEqual;
```

The positive side is that even if there were 100 properties, one or two (or more) loops would fly over it.

Please note that this code is not optimized and pretty naive.

More natural would be a fast-exit on first difference:

```
foreach(var prop in props_double)
    if(prop(first) != prop(second))
        return false;
```

..and/or observing that string.equals and double!=double can all be packed as the same object.Equals method (so you don't need separate props_string, props_double etc)

..and/or observing that you don't really need to list all properties, you can get them from Reflection, so you don't need to 'define' the 100 properties in these lists. (But then, you often have some special properties that you don't want to include.. so your reflection-way would need a way to detect and skip them..)

..and/or observing that if you used `struct` instead of `class` you would get full memberwise object.Equals comparison for free. (But then, structs differ from classes in many other things..)

..and/or(...)

All these 'optimizations' are highly dependent on what you have in the rest of the 14+ comparisons. It looks fun and smart at first, but the more the types of properties vary and the more types of comparisons you need to do (string.equals with case-insensitive maybe?) the worse it will get. Sometimes 14 times `&&`, or 14 times `if(x==y)return false` isn't really **that bad**.

Please don't get me wrong: **I do not advise you** to use the way I show here. I just show you that it is possible. Don't use it unless absolutely relevant and necessary. Doing it this way may cost you much more time than you would want to.

Answer (score 0):

This seems as a correct way how to do the compare.

If your aim is to be able to easily check if two different instances are equal you can override Equals() and GetHashCode(). 
You will be able to do:

```
x.Equals(y)
```

You can also override operator ==. In which case you can do:

```
x == y
```

Check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx) for details and example.

---

Also there is no reason for you (unless you want to use any extra parameters) to use

```
string.Equals(x.Name, y.Name)
```

use simply

```
x.Name == y.Name
```